# Stack around the variable 'uChar' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Here is the code which converts a hex string to byte array, it works fine but when the loop goes end and the complier reaches to the end of function it throws this error:
"Stack around the variable 'uChar' was corrupted"

```
void Cfsp::stringToHex(unsigned char hexArray[], LPCTSTR string)
{
    int stringLength=strlen(string);
    int j=0;
    unsigned char  uChar = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < stringLength; x+=2)
    {
        sscanf_s(&string[x], "%02x", &uChar);
        hexArray[j] = uChar;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Here is where I initiate the array and call the function.

```
unsigned char Key[16];
stringToHex( Key,"2f145a8b11d33217");
```

I know when stringToHex would convert the given string (16 chars length) to byte array it only fills 8 Bytes(as char). I just wanted to make a reserved area in the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get corruption is because you send `sscanf_s` an `unsigned char *` where it expects `int *`

Comment: do you mean i must to declare uchar variable as int and cast it to  char?

Comment: Yes, declare `int uChar` and cast to `unsigned char` when adding to `hexArray`

Answer (score 5):

This is why the `xxx_s` functions are *not* safe :-) People can misuse these safe functions as easily as the so-called "unsafe" ones.

`sscanf` with the `%x` format specifier wants an `int` pointer, not a `char` one.

It will write the entire (for example) 32 bit value starting at `uChar` and not caring one bit what it overwrites in the process.

It's only because you have stack protection enabled that the code catches this.

You should be using something like:

```
void Cfsp::stringToHex (unsigned char hexArray[], LPCTSTR string) {
    int stringLength = strlen (string);
    int j = 0;
    unsigned int uChar = 0;  // <-- INT rather than char.
    for (int x = 0; x < stringLength; x+=2) {
        sscanf_s (&string[x], "%02x", &uChar);
        hexArray[j] = uChar;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how sscanf_s works, but from the sscanf manpage:

x      Matches an unsigned hexadecimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably caused by `"%02x"` which requires an int as storage, not an unsigned char.

The issue could also be that you called `strlen(LPCTSTR)`. `LPCTSTR` might or might not have a terminating zero, if it doesn't `strlen` invokes undefined behaviour. Use `_tcslen(LPCTSTR)` instead.

Comment: hmm, your last point cannot possibly be the case given the way the OP is calling the function..

Comment: @Nim: Ah, didn't spot that, you're right. But I'm still leaving the info in for future reference :)

Comment: I think the other answers are right, but good point. He's mixing string types. LPCTSTR can be UNICODE or multibyte/ANSI (depending on preprocessor definitions), while strlen and sscanf_s are always multibyte/ANSI.